# How these identities with powers of small integers were found?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Recently I stumbled on the following picture:

[image]

I wonder how this was found. Is there any way to see why it is true, other than calculate it explicitly? Do such identities always exist for powers $1, 2, ..., k$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prouhet%E2%80%93Tarry%E2%80%93Escott_problem